# Convert epochTime to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I need to convert an epoch time value to NSDate..
For exemple I have this epoch value (long) : 81915536 
I'm interesting by the time value of the epoch value.

I have try that :

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:81915536];
```

but I got a 70's date....It's wrong.

But in a Java when I use this code, I obtain the right time value.

```
Date time = new Date(Long.valueOf(_epochTime));

    String minutes = time.getMinutes()+"";
    if(minutes.length()==1)
        minutes="0"+minutes;

    return time.getHours()+":"+minutes;
```

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

The current UNIX time is 1310407007  the seconds you gave are actually in the seventies, see here: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php.

Also, it doesn't seem that you check the year in your Java code, only the hours and minutes.

One more thing, if you want a constant to be treated as **long** and not as **int**, add a postfix of `L`: `81915536L`